# how to write this elaborately in ore lines of code to understand the concept?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

`dict = {x: arr.count(x) for x in arr}`

**want to break it in more lines of code how to do it? or is there any other way to write it to understand the concept clearly?**

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name.  Look up "Python dictionary comprehension" to understand how that expression works.  You can write it in more lines of code but I don't think that necessarily makes the concept easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop

```
arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 10]
dict = {}
for x in arr:
    dict[x]=arr.count(x)

print(dict)
```

Comment: you forgot the `dict=dict()` line